# Pygame: Local Scoreboard After Death With Input

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

In a game I am working on I am getting towards the later stages of my game. I am now at the point of which I want to add in a local scoreboard on which the player enters there name then that gets added to a scoreboard in which says 'Score:, Time:, Kills:'. Would I have to make a new file with its own class? Links to any places that could help with this scoreboard will be accepted too. All I need to really know is the code saying how to add in an input then saving that to the system locally. Thank you. Message me if you want to take a look at the code to help me with the scores. Thank you again.

Comment: Need some more info. Do you want players to input their names in a textbox inside the GUI? How and where are you wanting the text to be input.

Comment: Yes I would like them to input a name so they can show off. And for the text I want it to have titles at the top so "Name      Kills Time Score" then all info underneath. (I will be able to display the text (I hope)) It is just saving the info and the text box for the player I need to know. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your scoreboard is really advanced, then you can use SQLite, but for most scoreboard use cases pickle.dump() and pickle.load() should be enough (if I understand correctly) http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: Thank you. What would be included in an 'advanced' scoreboard?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. Some may say it's clunky, but it works seamlessly for me.

Basically, it reads from a text file and converts the data into a list to be edited, sorted, and written back to the file.

```
scoreboard = open("scoreboard.txt", 'r')    # Open file

scores = scoreboard.read()  # Put the whole file into a string
scores = [i.split() for i in scores.split('\n') if i]   # Convert string to list of lists
scores.append(['JAY', 1027, 120, 42])   # Add new name and scores to list
scores = sorted(scores, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[::-1]   # Sort the lists according to the second item in each (SCORE)

scoreboard = open("scoreboard.txt", 'w') # Open the file again to wipe it
scoreboard.write(str(scores).replace('], [', '\n').translate(None, ',[]\'\"')) # Write sanatized data to list

scoreboard.close() # Done
```

Play around with it!

Comment: Thank you. I will see how this goes :)

Comment: One question. How would I get pygame to 'read' that then display the info

Comment: You can just use the variable `scores` that's created; it contains all the data, then use pygame's font module. One annoyance with pygame though is that it can only render one line of text at a time with `font.render()`, meaning you have to iterate for multi-line text. For example; `for score in scores: line = font.render("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (score[0], score[1], score[2], score[3]), 1, (255, 255, 255)); window.blit(line, (0, 0))` ... or something.